# unable to edit in edit mode

Tags: mesh

I was following a tutorial in blender on basic stuff like nodes, texturing and what not, i tried to hide one of the meshes when I was in edit mode and it went grey. I'm no longer able to edit nor select the mesh. i'm a beginner so you may have to go in depth on how to fix the issue.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: Sounds like the mesh was separated with P instead of being hidden with H. Exit Edit mode to Object mode and join them back

Answer (score 1):

A screenshot will help to give a clear answer!

Try going to object mode again and going to edit mode. if you are not able to select the vertices or faces means that the object is a different from what you are trying to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the object selected in object mode.

[image]

Select the object in the hierarchy (Pictured above, should be on the top-right of your Blender screen). If you wanted to edit the cube, you simply click on the cube in this menu and now you can go into edit mode.

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you're in *Object Mode*, make sure to select the object and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If you're still in *Edit Mode*, do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess overlays are turned off. Image with two intersecting circles, one white and second empty (left from X-ray mode).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).